No .deb packages generated using bloom for ROS package with custom dependencies
I am currently trying to build .debs for my custom ROS package using bloom.
These are the steps I use for it:
roscd $PKG
bloom-generate rosdebian --ros-distro noetic
fakeroot debian/rules binary

One of the packages is very straightforward and it builds .debs without problems. The last few lines of the output looks like
dh_shlibdeps -l/workspace/src/package_ok/package_ok/debian/ros-noetic-package-ok//opt/ros/noetic/lib/
    install -d debian/ros-noetic-package-ok/DEBIAN
    dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/ros-noetic-package-ok.substvars -l/workspace/src/package_ok/package_ok/debian/ros-noetic-package-ok//opt/ros/noetic/lib/ debian/ros-noetic-package-ok/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/package_ok/pytransform/_pytransform.so debian/ros-noetic-package-ok/opt/ros/noetic/lib/package_ok/pytransform/_pytransform.so
make[1]: Leaving directory '/workspace/src/package_ok/package_ok'
   dh_installdeb -O-v -O--buildsystem=cmake -O--builddirectory=.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu
   dh_gencontrol -O-v -O--buildsystem=cmake -O--builddirectory=.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu
    echo misc:Depends= >> debian/ros-noetic-package-ok.substvars
    echo misc:Pre-Depends= >> debian/ros-noetic-package-ok.substvars
    dpkg-gencontrol -pros-noetic-package-ok -ldebian/changelog -Tdebian/ros-noetic-package-ok.substvars -Pdebian/ros-noetic-package-ok -UMulti-Arch
    chmod 0644 -- debian/ros-noetic-package-ok/DEBIAN/control
    chown 0:0 -- debian/ros-noetic-package-ok/DEBIAN/control
   dh_md5sums -O-v -O--buildsystem=cmake -O--builddirectory=.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu
    cd debian/ros-noetic-package-ok >/dev/null && xargs -r0 md5sum | perl -pe 'if (s@^\\@@) { s/\\\\/\\/g; }' > DEBIAN/md5sums
    chmod 0644 -- debian/ros-noetic-package-ok/DEBIAN/md5sums
    chown 0:0 -- debian/ros-noetic-package-ok/DEBIAN/md5sums
   dh_builddeb -O-v -O--buildsystem=cmake -O--builddirectory=.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu
    dpkg-deb --build debian/ros-noetic-package-ok ..
dpkg-deb: building package 'ros-noetic-package-ok' in '../ros-noetic-package-ok_2.3.0-0focal_amd64.deb'.

Another package has third-party libraries like OpenCV which we had to build from source. So I get errors like
# dh_shlibdeps -l/workspace/src/package_not_ok/debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok//opt/ros/noetic/lib/
#   install -d debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok/DEBIAN
#   dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok.substvars -l/workspace/src/package_not_ok/debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok//opt/ros/noetic/lib/ debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok/opt/ros/noetic/lib/libpackage_not_ok.so debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok/opt/ros/noetic/lib/package_not_ok/rgbd_export_service debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok/opt/ros/noetic/lib/package_not_ok/test_data_rgbd_camera debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok/opt/ros/noetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpackage_not_ok.so
# dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: can't extract name and version from library name 'librosconsole.so'
# dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: can't extract name and version from library name 'librosconsole.so'
# dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: can't extract name and version from library name 'librostime.so'
# dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: can't extract name and version from library name 'librostime.so'
# dpkg-shlibdeps: error: no dependency information found for /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.5 (used by debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok/opt/ros/noetic/lib/libpackage_not_ok.so)
# Hint: check if the library actually comes from a package.
# dh_shlibdeps: error: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok.substvars -l/workspace/src/package_not_ok/debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok//opt/ros/noetic/lib/ debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok/opt/ros/noetic/lib/libpackage_not_ok.so debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok/opt/ros/noetic/lib/package_not_ok/rgbd_export_service debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok/opt/ros/noetic/lib/package_not_ok/test_data_rgbd_camera debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok/opt/ros/noetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpackage_not_ok.so returned exit code 2
# dh_shlibdeps: error: Aborting due to earlier error
# make[1]: Leaving directory '/workspace/src/package_not_ok'
# make[1]: *** [debian/rules:59: override_dh_shlibdeps] Error 25
# make: *** [debian/rules:27: binary] Error 2

As a hack, I added these 2 lines of code
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.5 /usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.5
ls -s /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.5.2 /usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.5.2
ldconfig

Now I get no errors at all, but also no .debs are created.
make[1]: Entering directory '/workspace/src/package_not_ok'
# In case we're installing to a non-standard location, look for a setup.sh
# in the install tree that was dropped by catkin, and source it.  It will
# set things like CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, and PYTHONPATH.
if [ -f "/opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh" ]; then . "/opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh"; fi && \
dh_shlibdeps -l/workspace/src/package_not_ok/debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok//opt/ros/noetic/lib/
    install -d debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok/DEBIAN
    dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok.substvars -l/workspace/src/package_not_ok/debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok//opt/ros/noetic/lib/ debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok/opt/ros/noetic/lib/libpackage_not_ok.so debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok/opt/ros/noetic/lib/package_not_ok/rgbd_export_service debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok/opt/ros/noetic/lib/package_not_ok/test_data_rgbd_camera debian/ros-noetic-package-not-ok/opt/ros/noetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpackage_not_ok.so
make[1]: Leaving directory '/workspace/src/package_not_ok'

Edit 1: Based on some responses on SO, I created a shlibs.local file:
libopencv_imgproc 4.5 libopencv-imgproc4.5 (>= 4.5)
libopencv_imgcodecs 4.5 libopencv-imgcodecs4.5 (>= 4.5)
libopencv_core 4.5 libopencv-core4.5 (>= 4.5)
libopencv_surface_matching 4.5 libopencv-surface-matching4.5
libopencv_rgbd 4.5 libopencv-rgbd4.5 (>= 4.5) 

and now the .debs are generated, but I get errors now like
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-noetic-package-not-ok:
 ros-noetic-package-not-ok depends on libopencv-core4.5 (>= 4.5); however:
  Package libopencv-core4.5 is not installed.
 ros-noetic-package-not-ok depends on libopencv-imgcodecs4.5 (>= 4.5); however:
  Package libopencv-imgcodecs4.5 is not installed.
 ros-noetic-package-not-ok depends on libopencv-imgproc4.5 (>= 4.5); however:
  Package libopencv-imgproc4.5 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ros-noetic-package-not-ok (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ros-noetic-package-not-ok


Have you specified these dependencies in the debian/control file?
